# DMARC record not found

Tags: email, dmarc

I'm trying to set up DKIM, SPF and DMARC on my mail server. Although DKIM and SPF work fine (as reported by auth-results@verifier.port25.com) i can't seem to get DMARC to work.
Both [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com) and [dmarcian.com](http://dmarcian.com) report "No DMARC record found".

My DNS record is:

```
Type: TXT
Domain: _dmarc.domain.com
Value: v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:mail@domain.com
TTL: 5min
```

Both OpenDKIM and OpenDMARC on the mail server are up and running:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep -e opendkim -e opendmarc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8891          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8151/opendkim
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8893          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8168/opendmarc

cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep -e 8891 -e 8893         
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891, inet:127.0.0.1:8893
```

I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Check the SOA record for your domain to see how long negative caching might be. Until it expires some DNS servers won't re-qeuery. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/426807/how-long-does-negative-dns-caching-typically-last

Comment: If you gave the names involved maybe someone could help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namecheap [How do I add TXT/SPF/DKIM/DMARC records for my domain?](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/317/2237/how-do-i-add-txtspfdkimdmarc-records-for-my-domain) indeed has a problem in all of its examples, but the real reason is the missing tailing `.` for *root*.

> ```
> example.com   TXT     v=spf1 a ~all
> selector1._domainkey.example.com TXT
> _dmarc.example.com   TXT
> ```

That's why they don't work globally, while this form might work in their own web configuration tool. In BIND for instance the records that aren't FQDN with the `.` are completed with the `$ORIGIN example.com.`, making these examples:

```
example.com.example.com. TXT
selector1._domainkey.example.com.example.com. TXT
_dmarc.example.com.example.com. TXT
```

Both `_dmarc` and `_dmarc.example.com.` would work, but the short form only if the `$ORIGIN example.com.` was set, too.

Comment: Both `_dmarc.example.com.` and `_dmarc.example.com` didn't work for me. Changing it to `_dmarc` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Turns out the Namecheap Knowledge Base is wrong and the DMARC record needs to be *_dmarc* and not *_dmarc.domain.com*

Comment: Same as @Wolfgang, using "_dmarc" worked. I validated it worked by using http://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim.

Answer (score 0):

One should use a free [online DMARC record checker](https://dmarcly.com/tools/dmarc-checker) to check the existence and validity of a DMARC record on the domain in question. This issue occurs often because either this is no DMARC record found, or the DMARC record is set on an incorrect host.

Learn more with this post: [How to fix No DMARC Record Found](https://dmarcly.com/blog/how-to-fix-no-dmarc-record-found)