# Setup Google Domain with Google Compute Engine?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So I've recently bought a domain name from Google Domains, and have set up a virtual machine from the ASP.NET template available on Google Cloud Platform. I went through the tutorial on setting up Cloud DNS and setting my name servers on Google Domains and I believe I've done everything correctly.

I have already:

- Reserved my static external IP: `35.208.136.38`.
- Set up my Cloud DNS:

  - `A` record for `polytide.net`.
  - `NS` records (generated by GCP) for named servers `ns-cloud-e[n].googledomains.com`.
  - `SOA` record (not sure what this is, but generated by GCP).
  - `CNAME` record for `www.polytide.net`.
- Set the custom named servers on Google Domains to the above `NS` records.

I've performed a [DNS Query](https://dnsquery.org/dnsquery/polytide.net/ANY) and everything seems to be working; however, I can only access my website via external IP. I've tried pinging both the domain name and the external IP and only the IP returns a result. When trying to access my website via domain name I get the following error:

> `polytide.net`'s server IP address could not be found.
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I feel like I'm missing a critical point and I'm at a standstill. Also, not sure if this is important, but the VM doesn't have the firewall boxes checked for `HTTP` or `HTTPS`. I did check these boxes in an attempt to fix the issue, but it didn't work, so I unchecked them since that was the default that the template used.

How can I setup my Google Compute Engine website to utilize my Google Domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like everything is set up correctly, and I can access your website OK from here (it shows an "Under Construction" page).

Most likely, the `NXDOMAIN` result was cached in your local DNS server, or your ISP's DNS server, or your web browser. It will eventually expire and things will work for you. See [How long does negative DNS caching typically last?](https://serverfault.com/questions/426807/how-long-does-negative-dns-caching-typically-last) for more information.